# Binary built with Eclipse CDT visible only inside the IDE but nowhere to be found outside,What Is Happening?

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I am using latest Eclipse version with cmake4eclipse add-on on my Debian machine. I am a noob at using Eclipse and already there is a problem! The very strange problem is that after building a project the explorer tab of IDE shows the built binary but I can not actually find it using my usual file manager. When I try to run the binary from IDE, Eclipse complaints a nullpointer exception has occurred. What is happening here?

Comment: "I can not actually find it using my usual file manager" -- where are you looking? Can you post a screenshot of the Project Explorer view, and the project's location from the Project -> Properties -> Resource?

Comment: "When I try to run the binary from IDE, Eclipse complaints a nullpointer exception has occurred." -- is it Eclipse running into a nullpointer exception, or your program? if it's Eclipse, please check the `.metadata/.log` file in your Eclipse workspace directory for a stack trace.